# Which method of isSubstringOf() is more efficient?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, substring, std

could you please have a look at these 2 pieces of code that achieve the same result:

Someone else's solution:

```
bool hasSubstring(const char *word, const char *container) {

    if (container[0] == '\0' || word[0] == '\0')
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; container[i] != '\0'; i++) {

        bool foundNonMatch = false;
        for(int j = 0; word[j] != '\0'; j++) {

            if (container[i + j] != word[j]) {
                foundNonMatch = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (!foundNonMatch)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My solution:

```
bool isSubstringOf(string word, string container) {

    bool success = false;       

    // if either is empty, automatically return false 
    if (!word.empty() && !container.empty()) {

        // loop through the container and while not successful
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < container.size() && !success; i++) {

            // if the first letter of the word is found in the container...
            if (word.at(0) == container.at(i)) {                        

                success = true; // success is temporarily true

                // loop through the word to make sure it exists in the container
                for (unsigned j = 1; j < word.size(); j++) {

                    // if either a mismatch happens, or container is too small
                    if (container.size() <= (j+i) || word.at(j) != container.at(j+i)) 
                        success = false;    // set the flag to false again

                }

            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Which one uses less time and complexity?

As far as I understand, both are `O(n^2)` in the worst case, right?

Comment: Are you sure they achieve the same result, eg for empty strings?

Comment: @doctorlove Oh yeah, thanks for pointing that out, it's meant to return false when either string is "". It doesn't make sense that "" contains "". "" contains nothing. Question updated

Comment: The latter might keep checking size in each loop - if you're lucky it will be optimised away

Comment: *It doesn't make sense that "" contains ""* --- quite the contrary, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: "" is equal to "", but it certainly does not contain it.

Comment: You are grossly mistaken.

Comment: Feel free to explain yourself.

Comment: Or, even better, do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997204/does-an-empty-string-contain-an-empty-string-in-c

Comment: You are welcome to come up with your own definition of "contains" that excludes the empty string case. If it works for you, so much the better (you are welcome to share it here). However, such a definition does not seem very useful for anyone else. Feel free to check with any existing string or regular expressions library (there are quite a few of them out there), or consult any computer science text for a definition of "substring", or [look in the everyone's favourite source of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring#Substring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, rather than reinvent the wheel, you could just use:

```
container.find(word)
```

It's from the standard library so you can be confident that it is reasonably performant and correct.   You optimize for programmer time, QA time, user time (not shipping potentialy buggy code) by using well-tested, known building-blocks rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks, it was one of the review questions, so I felt like it would be an interesting exercise :)

Comment: Sure, nothing wrong with trying it yourself, see what's involved, and then using the library function in production code :).

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell of any differences in execution speed just by looking at two pieces of code unless there are obvious slowdowns.

Most compilers will optimize your code, therefore unless you like studying opcodes, telling which one will be faster pre-compilation won't be easy.

In terms of *speed*, you should benchmark the code. Stress it and see how it performs.

But **efficiency** isn't all about speed. You should also consider which one suits your coding style. Personally, I hate seeing random chuncks that you can tell before even studying the code that they were copy-pasted.

**+** Post it there instead: [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

They are both quadratic - every letter of the container is checked against every letter of each word in both cases. 

Since you asked about

> "time and complexity"

that connot be answered in general. See which is quickest on your machine.

Comment: It doesn't belong here after all.