# Does an empty string contain an empty string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, contains, portability, text-processing

Just had an interesting argument in the comment to one of my questions. My opponent claims that the statement `""` does **not** contain `""` is wrong.

My reasoning is that if `""` contained another `""`, that one would also contain `""` and so on.

Who is wrong?

P.S.

I am talking about a `std::string`

P.S.  P.S

I was not talking about substrings, but even if I add to my question " as a substring", it still makes no sense. An empty substring is **nonsense**. If you allow empty substrings to be contained in strings, that means you have an infinity of empty substrings. What is the point of that?

### Edit:

Am I the only one that thinks there's something wrong with the function `std::string::find`?

C++ reference clearly says

> Return Value: The position of the first character of the first match.

Ok, let's assume it makes sense for a minute and run this code:

```
string empty1 = "";
string empty2 = "";

int postition = empty1.find(empty2);

cout << "found \"\" at index " << position << endl;
```

The output is: `found "" at index 0`

**Nonsense part**: how can there be index 0 in a string of length 0? It is nonsense.

To be able to even **have** a 0th position, the string must be at least 1 character long.

And C++ is giving a exception in this case, which proves my point:

```
cout << empty2.at( empty1.find(empty2) ) << endl;
```

If it really contained an empty string it would had no problem printing it out.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Does an empty glass contain an empty glass?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking here

Comment: @jrok That's a different (and more easily resolved) question

Comment: @StephenTG Maybe. If you'd explain the difference, maybe I'd understand :)

Comment: Confusing question. Could be implementation specific. In a mathematical sense, I would assume the empty set contains the empty set.

Comment: @jrok I'm not really sure I can explain it, and I definitely can't answer the main question, but an empty glass doesn't have another empty glass in it, whereas the empty string is closer to the empty set, which can be said to include itself

Comment: @Nican If the empty set contained the empty set, it wouldn't be empty, so no, it doesn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo [According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set): Its only subset is the empty set itself. So if the only subset of the empty set is an empty set then the empty set contains itself?

Comment: You forgot to add *as a substring* to your question and got a type error. No string contains any other string *as an element* (elements of strings are characters, not strings).

Comment: @n.m. No, I didn't forget. I updated the answer

Comment: Empty string is not really empty, it contains 1 char of null terminator.

Comment: *I was not talking about substrings* --- your original question had **isSubstringOf** in the title. What else were you talking about if not substrings?

Comment: Be careful around `subset` and `substring`, they are not the same.  Also consider in C++ a string s with length 10.  `s.substring(0,0)`, `s.substring(1,0)`, etc.  There are 10 such substrings that return the empty string. If you have `string s = "";`, then `s.substring(0,0)` also returns the empty string.

Comment: An empty substring is nonsense inasmuch as addition by 0 is nonsense. After all, if we allow addition with 0, we'll have an infinity of adding 0.

Comment: @RyanWH What exactly is the difference between a subset and a substring then? I used the argument for myself, that if set `a` equals set `b`, `a` must contain all parts of `b`. An empty string equals an empty string, therefore it must contain it as well. Also, if one can get an empty string as a substring from any string, does that not imply that any string must contain an empty string?

Comment: Usually a secondary post script is P. P. S (post post script), not P. S. P. S.  :-)

Comment: I found this question to be relevant for [porting string-processing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46093100/2932052).

Comment: Return value
Position of the first character of the found substring *or npos if no such substring is found.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "contains".

The empty string is a *substring* of the empty string, and so is contained in that sense.

On the other hand, if you consider a string as a collection of characters, the empty string can't contain the empty string, because its elements are characters, not strings.

Relating to sets, the set

```
{2}
```

is a *subset* of the set

```
A = {1, 2, 3}
```

but `{2}` is not a *member* of `A` - all `A`'s members are numbers, not sets.

In the same way, `{}` is a subset of `{}`, but `{}` is not an element in `{}` (it can't be because it's empty).

So you're both right.

Answer (score 8):

C++ agrees with your "opponent":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool contains = string("").find(string("")) != string::npos;
    cout << "\"\" contains \"\": "
        << boolalpha << contains;
}
```

Output: `"" contains "": true`

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=61467abac6ae5c6c437309ca919523c6-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419)

Comment: Do you think you have found a bug in your C++ implementation?

Comment: @n.m. No, why? Come to think of it, it makes sense.

Comment: Just kidding. *Of course* it makes sense (but not to everyone it seems).

Comment: @n.m.: The standard defines the semantics of `std::basic_string<>::find` exactly like that, so no bug in the implementation.

Comment: Interestingly, my "STL implementation" (a very old one) gives a different result, and this is definitive [not a philosophical question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46093100/2932052) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It's easy. String A contains sub-string B if there is an argument `offset` such that `A.substr(offset, B.size()) == B`. No special cases for empty strings needed.

So, let's see. `std::string("").substr(0,0)` turns out to be `std::string("")`. And we can even check your "counter-example". `std::string("").substr(0,0).substr(0,0)` is also well-defined and empty. Turtles all the way down.

Comment: +1 rather good (and "pragmatic") explanation. Maybe the `std::string("")` should be replaced by `std::string()`

Answer (score 0):

Of course an empty string does not *contain* an empty string. It'll be turtles all the way down if it did.

Take `String empty = "";` that is declaring a string literal that is empty, if you want a string literal to **represent** a string literal that is empty you would need `String representsEMpty = """";` but of course, you need to escape it, giving you `string actuallyRepresentsEmpty = "\"\"";`

ps, I am taking a pragmatic approach to this. Leave the maths nonsense at the door.

Thinking about you amendment, it could be possible that your 'opponent' meant was that an 'empty' std::string still has an internal storage for characters which is itself empty of characters. That would be an implementation detail I am sure, it could perhaps just keep a certain size (say 10) array of characters 'just incase', so it will technically not be empty.

Of course, there is the trick question answer that 'nothing' fits into anything infinite times, a sort of 'divide by zero' situation.

Comment: You're missing the point. He's asking if an empty string is a substring of an empty string. Of course it is, because a empty string is a substring of all the possible strings.

Comment: `string actuallyRepresentsEmpty = "\"\""` is far from an empty string, it is a string with 2 double quotes!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas you missunderstood. It represents what you would need to 'program' and empty string. I am not saying that `"\"\""` is an empty string that contains an empty string, it is a string that contains what would **represent** and empty string.

Comment: -1 for giving a philosophical answer to a programming question.

Comment: Ok, *philosophical* was probably a mistake, sorry for that. But is your answer really helpful? An important point for everyday programming is if special cases matter. You must decide if you check strings against being empty before passing it to the functions like `find()` and since [you can get empty substrings from (empty) strings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/312982cb93cb499b), finding these (maybe "absurd") patterns is coherent behaviour. Do you think it would be possible to improve your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that is unclear is whether you are talking about `std::string` or null terminated C strings, the second thing is *why should it matter?*. I will assume `std::string`.

The requirements on `std::string` determine how the component must behave, not what its internal representation must be (although some of the requirements affect the internal representation). As long as the requirements for the component are met, whether it holds something internally is an implementation detail that you might not even be able to test.

In the particular case of an empty string, there is nothing that mandates that it holds anything. It could just hold a size member set to 0 and a pointer (for the dynamically allocated memory if/when not empty) also set to 0. The requirement in `operator[]` requires that it returns a reference to a character with value 0, but since that character cannot be modified without causing undefined behavior, and since strict aliasing rules allow reading from an lvalue of char type, the implementation could just return a reference to one of the bytes in the `size` member (all set to 0) in the case of an empty string.

Some implementations of `std::string` use small object optimizations, in those implementations there will be memory reserved for small strings, including an *empty* string. While the `std::string` will obviously not contain a `std::string` internally, it might contain the sequence of characters that compose an empty string (i.e. a terminating null character)

Comment: *requirements for the component* - this is definitely true. But have you a reference at hand, here these critical cases aren't covered: [string::find - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) ? The (old) implementation I've to use gives `string::npos` for `std::string().find(std::string())` and this seems not (or no more?) to be standard-conform, see [Coliru Viewer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35d776581eefd5c3) Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Wolf: I would not trust that particular source of documentation, consider using http://cppreference.com. The standard, C++03 is the oldest I checked, defines the result of the operation `xpos` as the location in the string such that `xpos + arg.size() <= size()` and the sequence of values in the object after `xpos` is the same sequence as the sequence of values in `arg`. The value `0` matches the requirements: `0 + empty.size() <= empty.size()` (`0 <= 0`), and since there are no elements in `empty`, the second restriction is trivially matched. That is, `anything.find("") == 0` by definition.

Comment: today I stumbled upon some strange test cases of mine (marked with questionable) and therefore searched this problem again. I think it's not about implementation details but about specification, so (sorry) this is distracting in my opinion. I added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46093100/2932052) that quotes at least Cppreference (as a deputy for "the standard")

Answer (score 0):

empty string doesn't contain anything - it's EMPTY. :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas there is nothing philosophical here. You just look up a definition in a textbook.

Comment: But the answer is a bit far from programming..., or is it not? `std::string empty; std::string also_empty = empty.substr(0,0);` seems to indicate that you can get a substring out of an empty string that is an empty string. Another question is what is the result of `empty.find("")` is 0, not `std::string::npos`, indicating that it found the empty string at the start of the empty string...

Comment: @n.m.: Well, if it is not philosophical then this answer is *wrong* on two accounts, it is not supported by evidence and it goes against what the standard states.

Comment: -1 this answer expresses a personal opinion. We should better not base software solutions on opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same question since I'm currently bound to a lousy STL implementation (dating back to the pre-C++98 era) that differs from C++98 and all following standards:

```
TEST_ASSERT(std::string().find(std::string()) == string::npos); // WRONG!!! (non-standard)
```

This is especially bad if you try to write portable code because it's so hard to prove that no feature depends on that behaviour. Sadly in my case that's actually true: it does string processing to shorten phone numbers input depending on a subscriber line spec.

On Cppreference, I see in [std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) an explicit description about empty strings that I think matches exactly the case in question:

> an empty substring is found at pos if and only if pos <= size()

The referred `pos` defines the position where to start the search, it defaults to `0` (the beginning).

A standard-compliant **C++ Standard Library** will pass the following tests:

```
TEST_ASSERT(std::string().find(std::string()) == 0);
TEST_ASSERT(std::string().substr(0, 0).empty());
TEST_ASSERT(std::string().substr().empty());
```

This interpretation of "contain" answers the question with yes.